# I find that some JS files in the common layout html are not available in the ng-view loaded file

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and making a headway.
However I came across this issue later in my work.
I have found that...

> Some non-angular JS files are not available in the partial-html loaded with the ng-view command through default AngularJS routing.

As I am new to AJs, so can anyone assist me to fix this problem.
I would really appreciate if the solution is given living in the default AngularJS framework i.e a pure AJs solution. I have seen third party workarounds which are sort of stepping out of the framework without being aware of any possible performance compromises.
Thank you.

Comment: You have `<script src="..."></script>` in the view? [No chance for it to work](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script). You need to include them in the main HTML page, or use something like [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) to dynamically load them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for answers for quiet a while I have discovered a pure AngularJS solution to the problem at last.

The solution is rather a complete repository on GitHub by a user so here is the link...
https://github.com/ikaul/AngularJS-Single-Page-App/tree/master/assignment5